# Avoid man in the middle secured Cookie deletion on subsequent conexiones

Tags: node.js, http, security, cookies, https

Lest's imagine a bad case escenario where an attacker is able to setup a man in the middle, obviously for non secured connections (HTTP:80)

on first connection:

```
1- cliente request example.com
2- server respond 301 to httpS::/example.com
3- client request https://example.com
4- server send document and a secured cookie (GOOD-COOKIE)
5- client send next request with GOOD-COOKIE
6- server respond based on GOOD-COOKIE
```

(days later client connect again from same browser)

```
1- client request example.com
X- Attacker intercepts and send document with FAKE-COOKIE (same-name *) and 301 to https
X- client overwrite the GOOD-COOKIE with the FAKE-COOKIE
3- client request https://example.com with FAKE-COOKIE
4- server respond based on FAKE-COOKIE
```

.* *NOTE: same name Cookie, even not secured (different flag), as transmitted over http from the attacker*

while secure Cookies are NOT TRASNMITED over http, indeed can be overwrite by a same-name cookie coming from a non https connection :sad-very-sad-emoticon

neither secure or httpOnly flags solve this matter, 
neither HSTS
neither ...

any tactic to overcome this problem ?

(we are developing in node.js, so no apache/iis/etc.. limitation apply)

**Cookies example for this case**

```
GOOD-COOKIE (header response)
Set-Cookie: myCookie=myValueCookie; Secure; Path=/

FAKE-COOKIE (header attacker response) Changed from original that server sends
Set-Cookie: myCookie=myValueCookie; Path=/
```

Comment: Use [cookie prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#cookie_prefixes) to avoid this issue altogether. It is impossible for attackers to set the specified prefixed cookie with their MITM responses to victim clients. However, the assertion that HSTS does not help to solve it is not strictly true, as clients that have already received this header will be guaranteed to make requests to the server over https, even when being told to visit it via `http://`. Now of course, it does not help clients that were compromised before receiving the HSTS header.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably HSTS. Not sure why you'd say it doesn't protect you here? It'll skip the connection over the insecure protocol and go straight to HTTPS, without exposing any cookies.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

It's as simple as sending a header telling the browser to only access your site over SSL for as long as you specify in the `max-age` part.

`response.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000');`

(31536000 seconds = one year)

It doesn't require any special servers or configuration.

Furthermore, you can [create a ruleset](https://github.com/efforg/https-everywhere/pulls) for [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/). This will only save a few users, but why not?

And last, make sure your SSL installation is solid. [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) is awesome for that!

Comment: The HSTS header only protects clients that have already visited the site to receive the header, it does not protect against clients that have already been compromised via an MITM attack, and it does introduce potential drawbacks if misconfigured.  While this does work it is not a complete fix.

Comment: And that's why a properly configured HSTS header should have the `preload` flag and should be submitted to https://hstspreload.org/

Comment: Yes, but HSTS does come with drawbacks and submitting to hstspreload.org is effectively additional configuration (thus counter to "doesn't require any special ... configuration") that may not be feasible to implement for every site (e.g due to organizational issues, or certain clients dragging their feet on getting SSL set up for all of their subdomains). For that it is best to use [cookie prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#cookie_prefixes) as I have referenced in the other comment as this would provide additional defense-in-depth measure.